How, if at all, does PayPal's "Pay in 4" feature affect credit score?
How, if at all, does using PayPal's "Pay in 4" feature affect one's credit score? It appears that it does not require a hard pull, so it does not lower credit scores; is this correct? Are the payments reported to credit agencies?

You'd have to ask the credit rating agencies  I think. Each has its own formula, and the formulas aren't published in any detail afaict.
